# Run sonar ant task using the command line - ClassDefNotFoundError

Tags: ant, sonarqube, pmd

I'm trying to integrate custom PMD tasks in Sonar, which I currently managed to work along with Sonar PMD plugin.

My current issue is to run sonar ant task with the command line.

In my eclipse workspace, I add additional classpath entries in Eclipse for Ant to run and it works just fine.
But when i run it in the command line, no matter how I pass the jars for ant, it just doesn't seem to be using it in the ClassLoader.

This is a big issue for my project, once I can't put the task to run in my continuous integration server.

I'm currently passing the jar's that contains all the classes need using the property sonar.libraries.

The error I'm getting is:

```
build.xml:121: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/pmd/AbstractJavaRule
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
```

Comment: Check the output of `ant -d target` (where "target" is the ant target that you are invoking) and verify that your classpath is being passed along correctly.

Comment: It doesn't show me the classpath when it's invoking PMD. That seems like a problem in Sonar Ant Task. Where can I get Sonar Ant Task source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"sonar.libraries" references only dependencies of your application, not dependencies of Sonar execution context.

If you want to develop custom PMD tasks that will be used by Sonar, please have a look at this example plugin: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-pmd-extension-plugin

- You just have to build the JAR of the plugin
- Put it in your "/extensions/plugins" folder
- And restart Sonar

Comment: Do I really have to build a plugin? Or is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Well, if you want to create custom rules using only XPAth, no. Otherwise, yes. But don't worry: building a plugin is as simple as building a simple JAR ("mvn clean install").